# How to perform the verification off the In-App purchase?

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I have just implemented the In-App purchase on my Flutter App.
I saw on various documentations that we should always verify the purchase prior to provide the benefits, but I can't figure out what that is really means.

The ***PurchaseDetails*** object provide the followings properties:

> - purchaseID
> - productID
> - verificationData
> - transactionDate
> - status

How are we supposed to use them for the verification ?

Thank you for your help,
Benjamin

Answer (score 5):

> but I can't figure out what that is really means.

It simply means that as a service provider, we should be double-checking a successful transaction with the payment processing authority (which is Google/Apple for Android/iOS IAP respectively) to prevent any form of fraud.

> How are we supposed to use them for the verification ?

https://pub.dev/documentation/in_app_purchase_platform_interface/latest/in_app_purchase_platform_interface/PurchaseVerificationData-class.html

PurchaseDetails.verificationData exposes two kinds of data (they are used the way they are named):

- localVerificationData
- serverVerificationData

Purchase receipt verification can be done either locally (i.e. on the client app) or on (your) server side. Server-side implementation is recommended for security reasons.

Now, this is where `verificationData` behaviour for iOS and Android changes.

- [iOS `verificationData`](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/main/packages/in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase_storekit/lib/src/types/app_store_purchase_details.dart#L47-L50)
- [How iOS IAP verification works](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/validating_receipts_with_the_app_store)
- [Android `verificationData`](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/main/packages/in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase_android/lib/src/types/google_play_purchase_details.dart#L36-L39)
- How Android IAP verification works

  - [Ref 1](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#Verify-purchase-device)
  - [Ref 2](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/security#verify)

Without going too much into the references (I think they are quite self-explanatory):

- In case of iOS, `localVerificationData`=`serverVerificationData`, and the purchase can be verified either by hitting the [`verifyReceipt`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/verifyreceipt) endpoint (can be done either on server-side or client-side), or decrypyting the data on the client/server-side and parse the decrypted data manually.
- In case of Android, `localVerificationData` carries the [`ProductPurchase`](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.products) data, that is otherwise returned by using the token provided by `serverVerificationData` to request the aforementioned REST endpoint. A purchase is considered 'verified' if purchase status is `PURCHASED`.

You may also have take care of other situations, depending on your use case.

Hope that the references linked above are useful.